# Overloading Method Efficiency

Tags: java, methods, overloading

I am wondering why is this consider a good practice of coding style.

```
public void advance() {
    advance(1);
}

public void advance(int numberofDays) {
// code here  }
```

I know that this way of writing overloading methods will let you have less repeated codes, but isn't it less effective? because you are calling another method.

Comment: This is *polymorphism*, and no it is not less effective (or measurably less efficient); Java is **very** good at making method calls.

Answer (score 0):

One View:

You can keep the processing logic centered in a single function, in this case the function with `//code here`

A Javadoc comment can be written on the function with no argument, to indicate that logic will be executed with default assumptions.

Function to function call within the JVM hardly causes any significant performance degradation, compared to benefits you get having better code structure

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Calling one method in another method is not less effective. 
Mostly people prefer doing method overloading is because of following reason

Let's say you created multiple functions with same code. Now the issue is whenever you want fix any bug you have to do it in multiple places. This is ok when you have a small project. In bigger products it's a huge task and testing effort also increases.